# How to configure Unity Z axis point up?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity the z axis is not pointing upwards, is there any settings or options that could be tweaked so that the Z-Axis point upwards.

Comment: Now when you are talking about the z-axis pointing upwards what exactly are you referring too? The GameObject, the Editor etc?

Comment: Everything, including the editor

Comment: Well if you are referring to the editor, you could click the compass on the top right until you get the Z-Axis on top, then just build the game from there.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.